# Jenkins pullRequest is deprecated

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm getting this warning message in my builds:

```
Warning: (PullRequestJob.groovy, line 3) pullRequest is deprecated
```

And I realize that pullRequest should be changed to something else, but cannot figure specific steps to be taken. I tried to use githubPullRequest as follows:

```
job('pull-request-job') {
  triggers {
    githubPullRequest {
      cron('H/5 * * * *')
      permitAll()
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work for me. When I build it locally with mvn I get:

```
(PullRequestJob.groovy, line 3) No signature of method
```

It seems like I either should somehow install githubPullRequest locally or use another approach. How to overcome this warning message?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36543298/1271460

Comment: Possible duplicate of [job-dsl-core jar version updated to 1.44 & githubPullRequest closure is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505926/job-dsl-core-jar-version-updated-to-1-44-githubpullrequest-closure-is-not-work)